# How to display user defined message who are restricted at Azure AD Enterprise Application level + ASP.Net Core

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I am restricting the users to login my ASP.Net Core (2.1) application which is deployed in Azure as described in the below link.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-restrict-users-from-accessing-the-azure-app-service-with-azure-ad-authent/

It is not allowing the users who are not assigned. But it is throwing as error. Please anyone tell me how to show custom message / view for handling this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to custom the error, the error message will be returned back to the AD App directly, it is not an error displayed on the login page which you can deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Joy Wang. I am asking like, how & where to handle the code to display message like "You are not authorized to access this application" when I got error / reply from AD.

Comment: @Kattesang When the user who is not assigned the role login to the app, you will easily get the error with dev tool (F12) as `AADSTS50105:The signed in user '{EmailHidden}' is not assigned to a role for the application '11exxxxx5ca7d57cbe'(webappname)`, just google for this line, there are many links promote you to add the user as the role in the app. There are also many posts in stackoverflow about this error, it is not difficult for the user to find the solution.

Comment: @Kattesang Any other concerns?

Comment: It was not worked out. Actually my requirement is to implement SSO using Azure AD. So I have enabled user assignment in Enterprise application by selecting my registered app. I have used that client ID in my code, but it allows me to login.Any other way to restrict the users who are not authrized to login and show them the message as "You are not authorized to view". Thanks.

Comment: @Kattesang If the user account was added to the `Users and groups` of the enterprise application, of course you can login, if you don't want the user to login, just remove the account from the `Users and groups`.

Comment: To understand the behaviour, I am asking. If the user try to login who was not assigned, then whether the user will restricted at login itself, or he will be redirected to AccessDenied View? (I am using ASP.Net Core 2.1). Because testing purpose, I have registerd two Apps. In App1, I was assigned myself and not assigned the other user. He was not even able to login. In App2, I was not assigned myself and assigned the other user. But I am able to login. In both behaviour, "AccessDenied" View was not landed. Really confused.

Comment: @Kattesang,Please ask your last comment as a new Stackoverflow question as it was not related to main question.

Comment: @Hari Krishna,  My last comment is also related to my main question. In ASP.Net Core 2.0, the Account folder has AccessDenied page. In later version it was removed. But some site it was mentioned that it can be called.So in my main question also I have asked for the possibility of loading custom View.